Trying to extract the left 4 characters from a string which are always a year (IE: 2017) But get a cannot convert error
This is the line of offending code:
LEFT(4, [DESCRIPTION]) AS ModelYear 

with "2015 CHEVROLET SILVERADO 1500" being the value in the column [Description].
This is the error message:

Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '2015 CHEVROLET SILVERADO 1500' to data type int

I don't care if it's an Int or not, I simply need to extract that year as a value. Can I turn off implicit conversion or something?

sometimes I'm an idiot.  The correct use of the LEFT has the column name 1st and the number of characters after.  IE:  LEFT([DESCRIPTION],4) As ModelYear
Apologies for wasting anyone's time
